# Understanding "we lose degrees of freedom in product deviations"?

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, intuition

I'm having a tricky time understanding the statement:

> we lose $n−1$ [degrees of freedom] by computing the product
>   deviations [in $cov(x,y)$]

I'm not necessarily looking for an overview of degrees of freedom, just an explicit pointer to grasp this claim. It comes from [here.](http://www.randomservices.org/random/sample/Covariance.html) Full quote:

> You may be perplexed that we average the product deviations [in $cov(x,y)$] 
>   by dividing by $n−1$ rather than $n$. The best explanation is that in the
>   probability model discussed below, the sample covariance is an
>   unbiased estimator of the distribution covariance. However, the mode
>   of averaging can also be understood in terms of **degrees of freedom**, as
>   was done for sample variance. Initially, we have $2n$ degrees of freedom
>   in the bivariate data. We lose two by computing the sample means $m(x)$
>   and $m(y)$. Of the remaining $2n−2$ degrees of freedom, **we lose $n−1$ by
>   computing the product deviations.** Thus, we are left with $n−1$ degrees
>   of freedom total.

Thanks, if you can rephrase the claim to help with understanding?

Comment: @whuber I'm asking for about the same claim as in your comment: "we lose $n−1$ [degrees of freedom] by computing the product deviations [in cov(x,y)]"